# Connecting R to a temporary table in db2

Tags: sql, r, db2

Is it possible to create a temporary table in db2 and connect it to R?

Comment: It's certainly possible to create a temporary table, but you cannot "connect" a table to anything.

Comment: The thing is, I do not have the privilege to create a new table in db2, that's why I thought of creating a temporary table (which I can) and connect that to R. Is there any other way besides creating a temporary table?